# Angular Router - Way to perform different action on separate clicks

Tags: angular, typescript

Exclude route from the button actions:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of allData" routerLink="/view-detail">
 <div>
   <p>{{data.content}}</p>
</div>
<button>SaveData</button>
<button>ApplyData</button>
</div>
```

When i click on the button - only the action particular to that button needs to be performed without route.
But when the div is clicked route triggers and when buttons are clicked route is also triggered along with button action.

How to perform on button click action without route, when buttons are inside the routerLink.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button (click)="save($event)">Save</button>

...


save(event: Event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // ...
}
```